# Processing time between strings and integers in C

Tags: c, performance, file

As we know the integer storage length is 4 bytes and character storage  is 1 byte.Here comes my problem,I have a huge data and I need to write them into a file.

For eg. my data is like

```
    Integers - 123456789 (of length 9) (Total 9! factorial records)
    Character - abcdefghi (of length 9) (Total 9! factorial records)
```

Which one will take less processing time? Any thoughts...

Comment: What does your 'processing' do? Is it IO bound or CPU bound?

Comment: So you have a huge set of data in your program's data structure and you want to write them in to a file?! is that correct?

Comment: @Sangeeth Yes I have huge data in my data structure and I need to write into a file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your integers are stored in individual 32-bit ints and you save them in binary, you have 4 bytes per integer and no conversion overhead.
If your character strings are stored in arrays of 9 chars and you save them as-is, you have 9 bytes per string and no conversion overhead.
In this case strings will take more I/O time than integers.

If you convert your integers into readable 9-char strings and save them the same way as the other strings, the I/O time will be the same, but there will be extra processing time for the integers required for their conversion into text.

Answer (score 1):

It's insignificant compared to the file's access time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the processing time is the same, since you have the same bytes! 
A file is stored in hard-drive, not in RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Using integer will save you some space and may be some time as well but it will be so small that you wont notice. As an integer takes 4 bytes and 9 characters will take 9 bytes. So for each value, you will be using 5 extra bytes. As the length of your data set is **9! = 362880**, so you will be wasting **362880*5** bytes which is 1.73 MB. This is very small chunk and writing it to disk will not be noticeable. So choose integer or character based on what suits you more and not based on which will be faster as you wont notice a difference for data set of this size.